# C++ CLI unable to delete the pointer passed to a dll

Tags: c#, pointers, c++-cli, wrapper

I am writing a c# (c++ cli) wrapper to get data from a dll (Written in C++). I am passing a CStringArray * to a function in the dll which fills up an array of string back to me. I can read the contents of it. But when I try to delete the pointer created by me (I do a new and pass that pointer to the dll function), I get access voilation exception. After going multiple threads discussed in SO, I feel that this might be happening due to version difference in dll and my wrapper. The dll is built using VS 2012 and the wrapper that I am writing is developed in VS 2010. Could this be a problem? I spoke to developer of dll and he confimed that he is just added some string and not doing any allocation in the dll. 
I wrote a test code (everything is vs2010) where in I have created a dll, a wrapper and test application. I can call delete without any problem. 
Request you experts to confirm if this is the actual root cause of the problem. Here is the code snippet (my test code). Production code is almost the same but crashes the moment I call RemoveAll().

```
    void MyDllWrapper::getLabels()
{
    CStringArray* data = new CStringArray;
    //FYI - mClass = new MyClass()
    mClass->getLabels(data); //Call dll to get the data 

    this->m_strLabels = gcnew List<String^>;

    for(int i = 0; i < data->GetCount(); i++)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Added string {0}", gcnew String(data->GetAt(i)));
        m_strLabels->Add(gcnew String(data->GetAt(i)));
    }

    data->RemoveAll(); //works fine
    delete data;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that cannot work.  The DLL is using a different version of the C runtime library and uses a different heap to store objects.  Your `delete` call tries to delete the object from the wrong heap.  Kaboom.  It is surely too late to redesign the DLL interface so this can never happen, you'll need to move forward by either asking the programmer to update to VS2012 or you to downgrade to VS2010.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the confirmation. I will check with the dll developer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ABI support in MFC, except for MFC extension DLLS and their consumers built in the same MFC version and configuration (Unicode/MBCS, Debug/Release etc). Mixing MFC versions definitely won't work.

A better way to pass the string array to you is to use a C style interface like a VARIANT of type VT_BSTR|VT_ARRAY or a string buffer containing double-null-terminated strings.

Comment: Jiang, can you please give me an example. Are you saying I should pass a variant type instead of CStringArray *? The code on the dll is not possible to modify. I can change the wrapper which I am coding.

Comment: Then ask the author what config was used to build the DLL you have, then build the wrapper with the same configuration. If you only have a Unicode release version of the dll, then you can't build a debug or MBCS version. If it is an MFC regular dll, then the author is breaking the rules and there's no hope to make this work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309277/heap-violations-when-releasing-a-cstringarray-parameter-from-a-dll-exported-fun for details.

Comment: Thank you for adding more details.